# We send the balance of the smart contrat using payable function to another smart contrat on gnosis safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

We send the balance of the smart contrat using payable function to another smart contrat which has a non payable address, is there any solution to make the transfer ?

https://snowtrace.io/address/0x1737796c5C090E8BC6CD1FAed5512633f95B457C#internaltx
check the internak tx

We sent this to gnosis safe which has a non payable address.

Is it possible to whidraw the funds to it ?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the contract uses `send` to transfer value.

Read more at:

- https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/
- https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5249851-why-can-t-i-transfer-eth-from-a-contract-into-a-safe

According to https://medium.com/avalancheavax/apricot-phase-two-berlin-eips-enhanced-avalanche-native-token-ant-support-c2ae0febe5bf the required EIPs are available on Avalanche, so you should ve able to use the access list to solve this.