# Adding our Gnosis-Safe addresses to our BSC auto-paying Smart Contract disables the contract

Tags: bsc, smart-contract-wallets, gnosis-safe

We are a coin operating on the Binance Smart Chain.

On Friday, we changed our "team owned" wallets to Gnosis-Safe.

These wallets receive automatic distributions from our coin's smart contract periodically throughout the day.

When we changed the addresses of our team-owned wallets to the Gnosis-Safe addresses, our smart contract was unable to make payment to our new wallet addresses during a distribution phase and caused a complete halt in trading as the contract 'hung' and waited for the transaction to complete (which it never did).

An initial contact to support indicated that I should manually perform a transaction with our smart contract through the Gnosis Safe and then everything would be resolved. I did so. Everything appeared to be resolved (no hung payment anymore) ... until the next payment needed to be made, which automatically hung the contract again.

Does Gnosis-safe have an inability to receive payments from BSC Smart Contracts without manual intervention? What can be done to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Gnosis Safe has all the capabilities of a regular EOA account. The distribution provider should investigate why it is hanging.

One of the potential causes could be that the distributor contract uses smart contract methods that are limited in gas usage - please check it here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/119759/65624