# Does bsc chain support eip2930?

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc

i hardcode use transfer to a gnosis-safe wallet, and it failed cause out of the gas. i found this [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119758/we-send-the-balance-of-the-smart-contrat-using-payable-function-to-another-smart/119759?newreg=40ae2341d7df4d26990bbe31cda8b266), and i use the eip2930 signer to sign a transaction. but when i send it to the bsc chain, it returns "invalid sender".

i clone the code with [github-bsc](https://github.com/bnb-chain/bsc.git), i find it contains the eip2929 and eip2930. anyone konw current bsc support the eip? thank u so much.

updated:
bsc doesn't support eip-2930 for now. just for wait..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the issue on their github they do not plan to enable this: https://github.com/bnb-chain/bsc/issues/784

> Sorry bsc doesn't support eip-2930. And we have no plans to do that in the near future.

Comment: oh, i see it. anyway, thank u so much.

Comment: wow, this sucks...